# How do I use flag within a script?

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

From the docs I can see that developer can utilize all cores available in the computer to speed up the recognition process using `--cpus n` flag (https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/)
which is to use when running `face_recognition --cpus 4 ./pictures_of_people_i_know/ ./unknown_pictures/` in a command line.

Is there an equivalent of this flag to be used within a script or do I need to use Python's `multiprocessing` module ? Docs don't mention this.

Comment: well you could always use `subprocess` as `face_recognition` uses multiprocessing under the hood itself. Also you could try to import the `main` function from https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/55b5c136292dcd4a1f5953f3eb3181235086efab/face_recognition/face_recognition_cli.py#L101

Comment: The library `joblib` has some interesting features, such as specifying `n_jobs` to run a piece of code.

Comment: @BijayRegmi  Yeah I figured I could go with `subprocess` and just call `run("face_recognition --cpus -1 ./pictures_of_people_i_know/ ./unknown_pictures/", shell=True)`. I'll see how that goes.